# Button gets clicked, div appears

Tags: jquery, html

Going crazy. I have no idea what I've missed here.

Heres the gist of it.

Got a button, when clicked, I want a div to appear. For some reason, it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input.mobile_menu_button').on('click', function() {
$("#nav").toggle("show");
});
</script>
```

This is the button

```
<div><input type="button"  class="mobile_menu_button"  /></p>
</div>
```

This is the CSS for the div thats hiding:

```
#nav {
background-color: #0CF;
width: 200px;
position: fixed;
display:none;
}
```

Can anyone help out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You syntax is wrong, check the [available arguments](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for `toggle()`. Maybe you meant `.toggle(true)`?

Comment: your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/d9MTC/

Comment: @RolandJansen I think it's working only because "show" is being converted to a `boolean true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    $('input.mobile_menu_button').click(function() {
    $("#nav").show();
});
```

Also, if you want this button open *and close* this menu, use this instead:

```
    $('input.mobile_menu_button').click(function() {
    $("#nav").toggle();
});
```

P.S - You should read about [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) because you've tried sending "show" as a parameter, but there's no such overloading for it.

**Edit:**

To complete this answer, like Roland said in the comments, the problem was that you need to bind this event only after the document's loaded

Comment: dot missing before click

Comment: Oh wow, thats fast.

No such luck though. I just can't seem to grasp what to do to make this work. 

You can see it fail here: http://jeffandmoira.com/html/

Thanks much for all the help!


**** sorry, shows up when you crunch down the window for mobile. Im just trying to get the mobile menu to show on click. 


Thanks again!

Jeff

Comment: @JeffMonk Please notice as people said that even your previous code (even though it was a bit mistaken) was supposed to work.  Remember to assign the click event to the button only after `$(document).load()`

Comment: Jeff, just fix it with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/d9MTC/1/ (see also http://api.jquery.com/ready/ )

Comment: The button doesn't show for you when you crush down the browser window?

Comment: Jeff, on your site you do not close the script tag starting in line 57 but open a new script tag in line 81!

Comment: Oh geez. You're right. Sigh. This is why I shouldn't be allowed to code. 

Thanks so much guys, once again you rocked the house. I should stick to photoshop and stop messing about in this stuff. I make one hell of a mess. :)

Cheers guys, thanks a ton!

Comment: 1. Your site looks really good. 2. I don't recommend stop doing things only because your currently not good at them is a smart idea! Enjoy the challenges!

Comment: Arg. Sorry guys, just one more question but its directly connected. When using the site on the mobile, the lovely menu button that you guys showed me works great. However, clicking a link on it leaves the menu open. I tried using the above code to toggle the links to change this, but it makes the menu dissapear when the site is full width. So basically, I need to make the links in the menu make the menu itself toggle display:none when clicked, but only when the width is under 768px. Is that possible? I was thinking maybe I have to add in a second class or something to the nav table?

Thanks :)

Comment: Nevermind! Figured it out! Score one for me!

Thanks again guys, you are the best. REally, really appreciate the help.